# Windows 10 thinks USB tethering is named Starbucks Wifi

Tags: windows-10, networking, usb, android, tethering

I have a Galaxy S8 running Android 9. I use USB tethering to connect to internet on my laptop running Win 10. Today the name of the connection is "STARBUCKS_WIFI 2".
Here are screenshots:

*Network Menu*

[image: Screenshot of Network Menu]

*Control Panel*

[image: Screenshot of Control Panel]

As you can see from the second image, device is "SAMSUNG Mobile USB..." that is my phone.

I tried troubleshooting, disabling and enabling the adapter. Replugged USB cable and toggled USB tethering on phone.

Why is this happening and can I fix it?

Comment: Is it possible that your home network is called like this?

Comment: @Aynos My home network has a different name. Also I connect to public access points at many coffee shops, Starbucks is one of them.

Comment: It may get confused. Try to delete your %temp% folders contents.

Comment: @Aynos I just figured it out. Still, I appreciate your suggestion :)

Comment: This can occur due to the network profile saved within the Registry whenever a new network connection occurs, so at some point in the past, the laptop had been connected to a network called `STARBUCKS_WIFI`, and for some reason, some of the data for the tethered connection matched that saved Registry key enough to result in an additional Registry network profile key that tacked a sequential integer onto it _(Windows won't automatically update those specific Registry keys, so when it sees a duplicate, it'll tack on a sequential integer to the network profile name shown for the adapter)_.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the reason why this happened but now I found a solution.

Fix is simply doing a "Network Reset".

Settings > Network & Internet > Status > Network Reset

After a reboot, I connected my phone again. This time, it is recognized as "Network" not "STARBUCKS_WIFI 2".

Note: If you are wondering, before this reset, I tried to manually "forget" the known network named "STARBUCKS_WIFI" but that did not fix the anomaly.

Comment: To manually remove the known network name if the Network Reset didn't do so, you'll need to search in the Registry for `STARBUCKS_WIFI` and manually remove the applicable key(s): _(before deleting any Registry key, export [backup] it first)_ `WinKey`+`R` → Open: `RegEdit` → _OK_ → Once `RegEdit` opens: `Ctrl`+`F` → Find What: `STARBUCKS_WIFI` → Tick box for _Match whole string only_ (all other boxes should be ticked by default) → _Find Next_ → To continue the search after a result is found: `F3`